# Overwrite of core class does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, configuration

I want to overwrite the class **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection**. But my new classes is ignored at the frontend. Any idea how to fix that? Is my config.xml wrong? Cache renewed several times.

Magic_Base.xml ( app/etc/modules )

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magic_Base>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Magic_Base>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Magic/Base/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php ( which is the overwritten class )

```
Magic_Base_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
    extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
```

config.xml ( Magic/Base/etc/config.xml )

```
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Magic_Base>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Magic_Base>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <catalog>
              <rewrite>
                  <resource_product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>Magic_Base_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection</resource_product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog>


           <catalog_resource_product_type_configurable_attribute>
              <rewrite>
                  <collection>Magic_Base_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection</collection>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog_resource_product_type_configurable_attribute>

       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not rewriting the class properly in your `config.xml`, it should be like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magic_Base>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Magic_Base>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>  
           <catalog_resource>
              <rewrite>
                  <product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>Magic_Base_Model_Catalog_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection</product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog_resource>

       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

### You have done lot of mistake

- **Magic_Base.xml does not define properly**

In this xml file `codepool` should `codePool` .P should upper case.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <Magic_Base>
>             <active>true</active>
>             <codePool>local</codePool> <!-- p should be UpperCase P -->
>         </Magic_Base>
>     </modules>
> </config>
> ```

- **Rewrite code is wrong in config.xml**

As you have rewrite resource class then you could not rewrite like this code:

```
  <catalog>
              <rewrite>
                  <resource_product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>Magic_Base_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection</resource_product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog>


           <catalog_resource_product_type_configurable_attribute>
              <rewrite>
                  <collection>Magic_Base_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection</collection>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog_resource_product_type_configurable_attribute>
```

it should be  `catalog`  from `catalog_resource`.

As per as ,magento  `catalog_resource` resource type class is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource`

*See  at config.xml of Mage_Catalog*

**So config.xml code should be**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Magic_Base>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Magic_Base>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
            <catalog_resource> <!-- change here -->
                <rewrite>
                <product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>Magic_Base_Model_Catalog_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection</product_type_configurable_attribute_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

- **File location:**

  Should be from

`app/code/local/Magic/Base/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php`

to

`app/code/local/Magic/Base/Model/Catalog/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php`

*Also need to class name:*

```
<?php
class Magic_Base_Model_Catalog_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute_Collection
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I like the flexibility of Magento - but sometimes this is really painful. 

The same issue again, located in /app/code/local/Magic/Base/Model/Eav/Entity/Attribute/Frontend

    class Magic_Base_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default

config.xml snippet

        ...
        <models>
        <eav_entity>
          <rewrite> 
    
    <attribute_frontend_default>Magic_Base_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default</attribute_frontend_default>
        </rewrite>
        </eav_entity>
        </models>

Comment: flexibility of Magento , is not my hand, You  need to follow magento process.Please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, I like the flexibility of Magento - but sometimes this is really painful.

The same issue again, located in */app/code/local/Magic/Base/Model/Eav/Entity/Attribute/Frontend*

```
class Magic_Base_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default
```

config.xml snippet

```
    ...
    <models>
    <eav_entity>
      <rewrite> 

<attribute_frontend_default>Magic_Base_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default</attribute_frontend_default>
    </rewrite>
    </eav_entity>
    </models>
```

It does not work. Is there any way to debug this - so that I see what magentos tries to open/call ?!